# Issue with ColdFusion Directory watcher Logs

Tags: logging, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, file-watcher, event-gateway

I am using ColdFusion Directory watcher and interval=60000; what we were observed, we are seeing the logs very continuously as below ( I have two directories dirWatcherLocal and DataFiles under Test folder)

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

E:\App\Test\dirWatcherLocalis directory

E:\App\Test\DataFilesis directory

...

...

..

My coldfusion-out.log has these data like hundreds of log entries

Comment: I dont want log the data as above. on every second I am not sure why above logs are created and coldfusion-out.log is with above data hundreds of lines.

Comment: There is not time stamp inserted into logs

Yes. it would every minute. How to stop to write into logs these data

Comment: Anyone know how to stop continues logs (logging on each second) as above in coldfusion-out.log. This Logs are due to ColdFusion Directory watcher